# VSTS Loadrunner or something better?

Tags: testing, loadrunner, stress

I am looking to get a comparison between stress testing tools that are available today. The options put forward to us are either VSTS or Loadrunner.

As of now, the inclination is towards Loadrunner, but we are looking to see if there is any better option today.

Comment: Wow, Down vote on a nearly 5 year old question? I admit that the question is quite open ended, was much younger and naive back then :p

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're testing. Static HTTP or simple JSP pages, use something free like jmeter. If you're testing ASP.net, silverlight or other MS technology stack apps, then VSTS is your best bet. For almost anything else LR works well, including newer Rich Internet Web 2.0 type pages including AJAX and Flex.

Loadrunner licenses are prohibitively expensive, if you're looking at a one off test, it isn't worth acquiring a license.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Apps you can rely on VSTS. They help you simulate

- Web Services Performance Testing
- Coded UI for functional testing
- Xpath Testing

patterns & practices: Performance Testing Guidance

- http://perftesting.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%3A%20Use%20Data%20Binding%20in%20Load%20Tests%20in%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Team%20System&ProjectName=perftesting